# google ml kit duplicate dependency

Tags: android, dependencies, google-mlkit

after adding `com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.0.7` I have below log error
what should I do?

Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$Builder found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentContainer found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentFactory found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Dependency found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.DependencyCycleException found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.DependencyException found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.events.Event found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.events.EventHandler found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.events.Publisher found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.events.Subscriber found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.inject.Provider found in modules jetified-firebase-common-16.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may have an existing firebase dependency that pulls in com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 which is not compatible with the mlkit APIs. You can resolve this by using the latest [firebase BOM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom) which specifies the latest versions for all firebase SDKs:

// Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')

// OR, just explicitly pull in the latest firebase-common dependency in your project:
implementation 'com.google.firebase.firebase-common-20.0.0'

Comment: Tried both but only the first solution works for me. Thanks! 